# Weights not converging while cost function has converged in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, loss-functions, training-error

I'm talking in an ideal scenario where a validation set isn't used. Without validation, as many epochs as possible are calculated. Training stops and finishes only when the loss function is minimized and converged.

Activation is sigmoid. My loss function is mean squared error, weights being in the squared error, so the loss function is a quadratic function of the weights. There's no hidden nodes. My cost/loss function drops drastically and approaches 0, which looks a sign of convergence. But the weights are still changing in a visible way, a lot faster than the cost function. Why do the weights keep changing?

Comment: How exactly do you measure how your weights are changing? What do you mean by you use no optimizer? Do you mean you use simple Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Comment: i have no idea about 'optimizer', which somebody asks me if i have it

Comment: i observe weights' change by looking at their number by naked eye

Comment: i use gradient descent, not even stochastic

Comment: How are you training the weights if you "use no optimizer"?

Comment: by 'optimizer', do u mean the learning rate can b optimized every epoch

Comment: @feynman the optimizer is the algorithm that you use to train the weights, which in your case you mentioned that it is gradient descent. Generally we do not monitor weights in neural networks and we do not monitor whether they have converged. Is the norm of your weights getting larger and larger? If so, you might want to use L2 regularization.

Comment: @Soroush the norms of my weights arent getting bigger. they just don't cease to change. in theory, if loss function is converged and minimized, weights should converge at the same time

Comment: Is there any activation function or is everything linear?

Comment: activation is sigmoid

Comment: You have three answers now: (a) weights diverge to infinity, (b) weights converge more slowly than loss and (c) weights oscillate around optimum. Looking at your data should provide some clues. At least (a) should be easy to reject or verify. (b) and (c) could be difficult to distinguish, as convergence could be oscillatory. So, provide more information about what you see. As soon as you have a good guess which answer is correct, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

**There is nothing strange about the effect you observe:** As long as the loss is not zero, the gradient will not be zero, and thus the gradient descent algorithm will keep updating the weights. How much they change in each iteration depends on the step size (learning rate) and the gradient. Unless you decrease the learning rate over time, your weights may oscillate around a local minimum forever.

Looking at the weights with a naked eye is not a very good criterion for checking convergence. However, there are various established strategies for deciding when to stop the learning algorithm. A common choices include:

1. Training for a fixed number of epochs.
2. Reaching a threshold value for training loss.
3. Early stopping: Monitoring the loss on a hold-out dataset and stop once it starts increasing.

A paper by Soudry et al. [1] studies the properties of convergence of weights w.r.t. convergence of the training loss in logistic regression models. They observe that the convergence of weights is *much* slower that the convergence of the loss. They suggest that it is beneficial to keep training even when the loss has seemingly converged and  recommend using accuracy on the validation set to be a good criterion for terminating the training. Note that their paper does not discuss explicitly deep neural networks which are much more complicated to analyze, however their earlier empirical results show similar effects in neural nets, e.g. [2].

---

[1]: [Soudry, D., Hoffer, E., Nacson, M.S., Gunasekar, S. and Srebro, N., 2018. The implicit bias of gradient descent on separable data. The Journal of Machine Learning Research, 19(1), pp.2822-2878.](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume19/18-188/18-188.pdf)

[2]: [Hoffer, E., Hubara, I. and Soudry, D., 2017. Train longer, generalize better: closing the generalization gap in large batch training of neural networks. In Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems (pp. 1731-1741).](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6770-train-longer-generalize-better-closing-the-generalization-gap-in-large-batch-training-of-neural-networks.pdf)

Comment: but my loss function is already minimized and converged->0. also i'm talking in a context where there's no validation set, thus gradient descent will always drive the loss function to its valley

Comment: If the loss is *equal* to zero, than the weights cannot change. I don't know where do you see the problem.

Comment: that's right. that's y i dont understand y my weights r changing

Comment: I suspect the loss is not *exactly* zero.

Comment: ok, that's also the only reasonable guess i've

Comment: Good observations and references.  A quick way to formulate it: If the loss function is quadratic in the parameters around the minimum, then a change of order $\epsilon$ in the weights near the minimum will only give a change of order $O(\epsilon^2)$ in the value of the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly possible in problems where a simpler neural network would have done the job. Think for example of a neural network that takes an input, passes it into a hidden layer (consisting of only one neuron) and then returns the output, which should be always 0.

Here we have two connections, but the only relevant one is the second. The value of the first one is irrelevant and therefore it could be changing arbitrarely producing always the same error.

Comment: no, my output isn't always 0. the loss function drops from a positive value to a value approaching 0

Comment: If the loss function does not depend on one of the parameters, then this parameter should remain fixed after all "relevant" parameters have converged. Of course, that might depend on the particular optimization algorithm, but it should hold for any gradient based algorithm, even stochastic gradient.

Comment: @feynman Yes, of course, if your problem is more complex, the issue will not be than simple I just posted about the simplest example where this phenomenon may happen

Comment: @jarauh You are right. A gradient-based descent will just choose an arbitrary value for that irrelevant parameter (this does not have to hold for other optimization algorithms). However, if its influence is close to 0 and has high variance depending on the sample, stochastic methods may keep tis value "shaking"

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that the optimal weights are at infinity. Nevertheless, the loss function will be almost optimal already for finite weights. Thus, the weights can still grow notably, even though the loss function has converged already.

For some loss functions, such as the negative log-likelihood without regularization, this is a common phenomenon. Infinite weights are needed for the network to represent zero probabilities.

Comment: how can it b possible to minimize the loss function by weights being infinity? the loss function is bound to b infinity at infinite weights, as it's a convex function

Comment: $1/x$ is also a convex function that is minimized at infinity.

Comment: but i'm using a mean squared error loss function

Comment: You have to consider your loss function as a function of the network weights.  Are you sure that your loss function is convex in the network weights?  In any case, infinite weights may lead to a well-defined behaviour of the network and a finite value of the loss function.

Comment: yes, loss function is mean squared error, weights being in the squared error. so the loss function is a quadratic function of the weights

Comment: To discuss this further, please edit your question and add more precise information (preferably formulae) about your setup. As soon as your network has hidden nodes it is almost impossible to have a convex loss function. Without hidden nodes, things are slightly different.

Comment: edited. pls c the question again